# How to use windows-phone exclusive code in a xaml code file (Win-Uiniversal App)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Does anyoneone know how to write windows-phone exclusive code in a xaml code file (universal app)? e.x. when I want to use another design for my W8.1 app as for my WP8.1 app.

I moved the MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs to the ".Shared" folder, and thus I use the same code for both platforms.

so in Mainpage.xaml.cs I could use

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP

#endif
```

but whats the equivalent for the xaml code?

I hope you understand my question
Thanks in advance, Christian

Comment: Why not just have two different XAML files (with the same name) in each target's project, rather than putting it in the shared pseudo project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent for XAML.  You can create a userconteol that is forked between the project types and then reference this usercontrol from the shared xaml